# Numpy Slicing - Calculate Matrix PseudoInverses without Iteration from 3x3 array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have *N*, *2x4* arrays stored in a (*2x4xN*) array `J`. I am trying to calculate the pseudoinverse for each of the *N*, *2x4* arrays, and save the pseudoinverses to a (N x 4 x 2) array `J_pinv`.

What I'm currently doing:

```
J_pinvs = np.zeros((N, 4, 2))
for i in range(N):
    J_pinvs[i, :, :] = np.transpose(J[:, :, i]) @ np.linalg.inv(J[:, :, i] @ J[:, :, i].transpose())
```

This works but I would like to speed up the compute time as this will be running in a layer of a neural network so I would like to make it as fast as possible.

What I've tried:

```
J_pinvs = np.zeros((N, 4, 2))
J_pinvs2[:, :, :] = np.transpose(J[:, :, :]) @ np.linalg.inv(J[:, :, :] @ J[:, :, :].transpose())
```

*Generates the error*:

```
<ipython-input-87-d8ee1ba2ae5e> in <module>
      1 J_pinvs2 = np.zeros((4, 2, 3))
----> 2 J_pinvs2[:, :, :] = np.transpose(J[:, :, :]) @ np.linalg.inv(J[:, :, :] @ J[:, :, :].transpose())

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 4 is different from 3)
```

Is there a way to do this with slicing so that I don't need to use an iterator? I'm having trouble finding anything online. Any help/suggestions would be appretiated!

Thanks,
JM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to specify how to transpose a 3-D array:

```
np.linalg.inv(a @ a.transpose(0,2,1))
```

will work. As oppose to

```
# sample data
a = np.arange(24).reshape(-1,2,4)

a.shape 
# (3, 2, 4)

a.transpose().shape
# (4, 2, 3)
```

and

```
a @ a.transpose()
```

will not work.

Finally, the whole script should be:

```
a.transpose(0,2,1) @ np.linalg.inv(a @ a.transpose(0,2,1))
```